# How to notify Group manager when user subscribe a group

Tags: organic-groups, privatemsg

I am using [Organic groups](https://drupal.org/project/og) and [Privatemsg](https://drupal.org/project/privatemsg), and I'd like to notify (send private message) the group manager when someone is asking for membership of the group (subscribe).

I think maybe I can use Rules, but I am new to Rules and do not know how to set arguments and parameters.

Is there any modules or code snippets can do this?